# Efficient way to get multiple time interval based sums?

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

Is there an efficient way to get the sums over multiple time ranges for multiple groups (example below)?

I'm using MySQL 8.

PS: I struggled really hard to formulate this question as clear as it could be. I would gladly accept suggestions to make it more clear/understandable...

---

**OBS:**

- Considering '2020-05-07 16:20:00' as the "current time".
- Each id represents one automatic pluviometric station (rain gauge)

**RAW TABLE:**

```
SELECT* FROM pluv_reg ORDER BY dth DESC;

id   dth                    valor
1    2020-05-07 16:20:00    5.0
2    2020-05-07 16:20:00    5.0
3    2020-05-07 16:20:00    5.0
4    2020-05-07 16:20:00    5.0
1    2020-05-07 16:15:00    5.0
2    2020-05-07 16:15:00    5.0
...
```

**DESIRED RETURN:**

```
id   dth                    m05     m15    m30     h01     h24      h48      h96
1    2020-05-07 16:20:00    5.0    15.0    60.0    60.0    100.0    100.0    196.0
2    2020-05-07 16:20:00    5.0    15.0    60.0    60.0    100.0    100.0    197.0
3    2020-05-07 16:20:00    5.0    15.0    60.0    60.0    100.0    100.0    198.0
4    2020-05-07 16:20:00    5.0    15.0    60.0    60.0    100.0    100.0    199.0
1    2020-05-07 16:15:00    5.0    15.0    55.0    55.0    95.0     95.0     191.0
2    2020-05-07 16:15:00    5.0    15.0    55.0    55.0    95.0     95.0     192.0
3    2020-05-07 16:15:00    5.0    15.0    55.0    55.0    95.0     95.0     193.0
...

LEGEND
Column m05 -> Sum of "valor" of the last 05 minutes for that "id" at that time
...
Column m30 -> Sum of "valor" of the last 30 minutes for that "id" at that time
...
Column h48 -> Sum of "valor" of the last 48 hours for that "id" at that time
```

**CURRENT QUERY:**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT pluv_reg.id,
            pluv_reg.dth,
            SUM(pluv_reg.valor)  OVER w05 AS 'm05',
            SUM(pluv_reg.valor)  OVER w15 AS 'm15',
            SUM(pluv_reg.valor)  OVER w30 AS 'm30',
            SUM(pluv_reg.valor)  OVER w1 AS 'h01',
            SUM(pluv_reg.valor)  OVER w24 AS 'h24',
            SUM(pluv_reg.valor)  OVER w48 AS 'h48',
            SUM(pluv_reg.valor)  OVER w96 AS 'h96'
    FROM pluv_reg

    # this WHERE clause ensures that all the rows I need have the correct values ______________________________
    WHERE pluv_reg.dth > DATE_SUB(CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME), INTERVAL 98 HOUR)

    WINDOW  w05 AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dth RANGE INTERVAL '0:04' HOUR_MINUTE PRECEDING),
            w15 AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dth RANGE INTERVAL '0:14' HOUR_MINUTE PRECEDING),
            w30 AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dth RANGE INTERVAL '0:29' HOUR_MINUTE PRECEDING),
            w1 AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dth RANGE INTERVAL '0:59' HOUR_MINUTE PRECEDING),
            w24 AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dth RANGE INTERVAL '23:59' HOUR_MINUTE PRECEDING),
            w48 AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dth RANGE INTERVAL '47:59' HOUR_MINUTE PRECEDING),
            w96 AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dth RANGE INTERVAL '95:59' HOUR_MINUTE PRECEDING)
    ) subquery

# this HAVING clause returns only the rows I need _____________________________________________________________
HAVING subquery.dth >= DATE_SUB(CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME), INTERVAL 2 HOUR);
```

My **CURRENT QUERY** (above) works, but it takes a very long time on my actual production table (up to 10 seconds. I would like to speed up to something like 10 times faster, at least).

The problem with my **CURRENT QUERY** is that **it calculates those sums for all the rows** of the last 98 hours (*WHERE pluv_reg.dth > DATE_SUB(CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME), INTERVAL 98 HOUR)*) even though **I only need those sums for the last 2 hours** (*HAVING subquery.dth >= DATE_SUB(CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)*) ;

With the example below, the **subquery** itself produces 32 rows (40.000 on production). The **HAVING** clause filters it to only 20 rows (700 on production) - those are the only rows I need.

**CREATE and INSERT statements:**

```
CREATE TABLE pluv_reg (
id INT,
dth DATETIME,
valor DECIMAL(5,1),

PRIMARY KEY(id, dth)
);

INSERT INTO pluv_reg (id,dth,valor) VALUES
(1, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 0 MINUTE), 5),
(1, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE), 5),
(1, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE), 5),
(1, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE), 5),
(1, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE), 40),
(1, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 10 HOUR), 40),
(1, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 60 HOUR), 72),
(1, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 90 HOUR), 24),

(2, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 0 MINUTE), 5),
(2, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE), 5),
(2, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE), 5),
(2, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE), 5),
(2, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE), 40),
(2, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 10 HOUR), 40),
(2, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 60 HOUR), 72),
(2, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 90 HOUR), 24),

(3, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 0 MINUTE), 5),
(3, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE), 5),
(3, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE), 5),
(3, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE), 5),
(3, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE), 40),
(3, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 10 HOUR), 40),
(3, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 60 HOUR), 72),
(3, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 90 HOUR), 24),

(4, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 0 MINUTE), 5),
(4, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE), 5),
(4, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE), 5),
(4, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE), 5),
(4, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE), 40),
(4, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 10 HOUR), 40),
(4, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 60 HOUR), 72),
(4, (CAST('2020-05-07 16:20:00' AS DATETIME) - INTERVAL 90 HOUR), 24)
;
```